# Regular Expression to get full string if it doesn't contain a specific character?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need help with a regular expression that will find matches in the strings below:

> myDOG_test
>
> myCAT_test

Basically, I want to return 'DOG' or 'CAT' from these paths.

Then I have similar strings (all start with 'my') that don't contain the underscore AFTER the value I want, and in that case I just want to return the FULL string -- in a match group.

> myCentralReports
>
> myDEMO3

This is the REGEXP that I have so far:

```
.*?my(.*?)\_.*
```

This correctly puts CAT & DOG in the matching group, but I'm having problems matching the other 2 strings. Obviously I left the hardcoded underscore in there just to show you what I started with -- but I need to modify this for the other case.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'/\smy(.+?)[_|\s]/'
```

This will get anything between a whitespace character followed by "my", and the next trailing underscore or whitespace character. try it out.

Comment: This gave me a good start.  I ended up getting as close as I could -- then handling the rest in code (doing search and replace).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need regex:

```
explode('_', $string);
```

First element will contain `myDOG` or `myDEMO3`. Remove `'my'` if needed, it's not clear whether you want `'my'` in your second case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
$list = array(' myDOG_test', 'myCAT_test',' myCentralReports', 'myDEMO3');

foreach($list as $elem) {
  preg_match("/^\s*my(.+?)(?:_|$)/", $elem, $m);
  echo "$elem : matches = ";print_r($m);
}
```

**Output:**

```
 myDOG_test : matches = Array
(
    [0] =>  myDOG_
    [1] => DOG
)
myCAT_test : matches = Array
(
    [0] => myCAT_
    [1] => CAT
)
 myCentralReports : matches = Array
(
    [0] =>  myCentralReports
    [1] => CentralReports
)
myDEMO3 : matches = Array
(
    [0] => myDEMO3
    [1] => DEMO3
)
```